# Keytype invalid or not supported here" while doing encrypted communication via UFTP

Tags: windows, udp, file-transfer, qnx, reliable-multicast

I am running uftp on windows and uftpd on qnx Rtos.
When I am sending unencrypted data its woking fine for me . I am using below commands to send unencrypted data.

```
 UFTP: uftp -Y none -h sha1 -r 0.5:0.5:0.5 -t 20 -s 10 -M 230.4.4.1 -P 
 230.5.5.1 -p 32322 D:\FTPServer\automationbuild\options-350-19-
 01B_7830_7835none.dat

UFTPD: "/usr/bin/uftpd", "uftpd", "-M",
(const char )m_puftpfiletransferparams->m_MulticastIp, "-p",
(const char )m_puftpfiletransferparams->m_iPort, "-D",
"/ram/tmp",NULL
```

Its working fine and I am getting logs

```
UFTP version 4.9.4 Copyright (C) 2001-2017 Dennis A. Bush
Starting at Sat Dec 9 21:20:57 2017
Transfer rate: 1000 Kbps (125 KB/s)
Wait between packets: 10562 us
Using private multicast address 230.5.5.1 Group ID: 112029B8
Initializing group
Sending ANNOUNCE 1
Sending ANNOUNCE 2
Received REGISTER from client 0x0A026CE3
Sending REG_CONF 3.1
Sending ANNOUNCE 3
Sending ANNOUNCE 4
Sending ANNOUNCE 5
Sending ANNOUNCE 6
Sending ANNOUNCE 7
Sending ANNOUNCE 8
Sending ANNOUNCE 9
Sending ANNOUNCE 10
----- options-350-20-01A_6626_7808_7809.dat -----
File ID: 0001 Name: options-350-19-01B_7830_7835none.dat
sending as: options-350-19-01B_7830_7835none.dat
Bytes: 6096 Blocks: 5 Sec
```

When I tried sending the encrypted data I faced Issue . I am using commands

```
 UFTP: uftp -Y des -h sha1 -r 0.5:0.5:0.5 -t 20 -s 10 -M 230.4.4.1 -P 
 230.5.5.1 -p 32322 D:\FTPServer\automationbuild\options-350-19-
 01B_7830_7835none.dat

 UFTPD: "/usr/bin/uftpd", "uftpd", "-M",
 (const char )m_puftpfiletransferparams->m_MulticastIp, "-p",
 (const char )m_puftpfiletransferparams->m_iPort, "-D",
 "/ram/tmp",NULL
```

I am getting error logs saying keytype Invalid

```
UFTP version 4.9.4 Copyright (C) 2001-2017 Dennis A. Bush
Starting at Sat Dec 9 21:20:05 2017
Loaded 512 bit RSA key with fingerprint 
BA:2A:C2:1A:3B:1A:2A:59:A3:D1:14:3A:7A:92:79:93:6D:D8:BD:28
Transfer rate: 1000 Kbps (125 KB/s)
Wait between packets: 11031 us
Using private multicast address 230.5.5.1 Group ID: 6EE9BB50
Initializing group
Sending ANNOUNCE 1
Sending ANNOUNCE 2
Transfer aborted by 0A026CE3: Keytype invalid or not supported here
Sending ANNOUNCE 3
Transfer aborted by 0A026CE3: Keytype invalid or not supported here
Sending ANNOUNCE 4
Transfer aborted by 0A026CE3: Keytype invalid or not supported here
Sending ANNOUNCE 5
Transfer aborted by 0A026CE3: Keytype invalid or not supported here
Sending ANNOUNCE 6
Transfer aborted by 0A026CE3: Keytype invalid or not supported here
Sending ANNOUNCE 7
Transfer aborted by 0A026CE3: Keytype invalid or not supported here
Sending ANNOUNCE 8
Transfer aborted by 0A026CE3: Keytype invalid or not supported here
Sending ANNOUNCE 9
Transfer aborted by 0A026CE3: Keytype invalid or not supported here
Sending ANNOUNCE 10
Transfer aborted by 0A026CE3: Keytype invalid or not supported here
Announce timed out
uftp: Finishing at Sat Dec 9 21:20:20 2017
```

There are similar errors on the receiving side:

```
UFTP version 4.7 Copyright (C) 2001-2015 Dennis A. Bush
2013/04/20 05:48:33.175124: tos / traffic class byte = 00
2013/04/20 05:48:33.266040: [1C17429A/00:0]: Keytype invalid or not supported here
2013/04/20 05:48:34.671744: tos / traffic class byte = 00
2013/04/20 05:48:34.687729: [1C17429A/00:0]: Keytype invalid or not supported here
2013/04/20 05:48:36.169363: tos / traffic class byte = 00
2013/04/20 05:48:36.184350: [1C17429A/00:0]: Keytype invalid or not supported here
2013/04/20 05:48:37.668981: tos / traffic class byte = 00
2013/04/20 05:48:37.685965: [1C17429A/00:0]: Keytype invalid or not supported here
2013/04/20 05:48:39.163603: tos / traffic class byte = 00
2013/04/20 05:48:39.178589: [1C17429A/00:0]: Keytype invalid or not supported here
2013/04/20 05:48:40.661223: tos / traffic class byte = 00
2013/04/20 05:48:40.676209: [1C17429A/00:0]: Keytype invalid or not supported here
2013/04/20 05:48:42.157843: tos / traffic class byte = 00
2013/04/20 05:48:42.172829: [1C17429A/00:0]: Keytype invalid or not supported here
2013/04/20 05:48:43.655462: tos / traffic class byte = 00
2013/04/20 05:48:43.669450: [1C17429A/00:0]: Keytype invalid or not supported here
2013/04/20 05:48:45.152083: tos / traffic class byte = 00
2013/04/20 05:48:45.168068: [1C17429A/00:0]: Keytype invalid or not supported here
```

I am not getting what else I need to make it work . Do I need to add -k or -K both side , If I am not adding this will it not work ?? What I understood is if I am not using -k it will by default generate 512 bit rsa key.

I am not getting any help regarding this .Please help me to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the [discussion thread on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/uftp-multicast/discussion/general/thread/62d2e732/), the receiver logs don't show any messages regarding loading or generating a key on startup.  This indicates that the receiver was compiled without encryption support.

You'll need to rebuild the receiver to enable encryption.